# The decimal.Decimal() function is producing an unrounded result

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, decimal, number-formatting

I am new to Python and I am having trouble with the Decimal function in the decimal module in Python. I understand that due to the way that Python stores float values in memory, in order to perform calculations on them to generate a human readable result, we can either use the round function on our result or use the decimal.Decimal() function.

In the code below, I've created a class calc1 which simply returns the addition and difference of two numbers. Yet whenever I run it, even though I've included decimal.Decimal() in my code, the result continues to be unrounded.

Code:

```
    import decimal as dec

    class calc1:
            'calc1 class is used for addition, subtraction only'
            obj_count = 0

            def __init__(self, value1, value2):
                    self.value1 = value1
                    self.value2 = value2
                    calc1.obj_count = calc1.obj_count + 1

            def add(self):
                    return dec.Decimal(self.value1 + self.value2)

            def sub(self):
                    return dec.Decimal(self.value1 - self.value2)

            def __str__(self):
                    return str(self.add()) + " " + str(self.sub())

    obj_list = []

    for i in range(5):
            obj_list.append(calc1(3 * i, 5.6 * i))
            print(obj_list[i])
```

Output:

0.0 0
8.6 -2.5999999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375
17.2 -5.199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
25.799999999999997 -7.7999999999999971578290569595992565155029296875
34.4 -10.39999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375

Comment: `5.6` is a native floating-point value before it reaches the `decimal` module, and `5.6 * i` performs a native floating-point operation without using the `decimal` module. I do not use Python much and do not use the `decimal` module, but I expect you will want to start with `"5.6"` as a string, convert that to a `decimal` value, and then continue arithmetic from there, completely avoiding the native Python floating-point.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are handing a value that already has floating point precision to your class and in turn the `Decimal` class.

You can avoid this by just handing `Decimal` a string representation of the number you wish to assign to it.

```
from decimal import Decimal

class Calc1:
    def __init__(self, val_1, val_2):
        # these are now Decimal objects
        self.val_1 = val_1
        self.val_2 = val_2
    
    def add(self):
        # the Decimal conversion can be removed here
        # since both numbers are already Decimals
        return self.val_1 + self.val_2

    def sub(self):
        return self.val_1 - self.val_2
   
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.add()) + " " + str(self.sub())

lst = []
for i in range(5):
    i_as_dec = Decimal(i)
    # Here we multiply a decimal representation of each of our numbers
    # this will hand a Decimal object to the Calc1 class
    lst.append(Calc1(Decimal('3') * i_as_dec, Decimal('5.6') * i_as_dec))
    print(lst[i])
```

Output:

```
0.0 0.0
8.6 -2.6
17.2 -5.2
25.8 -7.8
34.4 -10.4
```

Comment: Is there any way to convert a float variable to a decimal though? I tried to pass a float converted to a string to Decimal() and it seems to still only be working half the time. I just edited 2 lines in my original code:                                                                                                        
self.value1 = dec.Decimal(str(value1))
self.value2 = dec.Decimal(str(value2))           and it did not work

Comment: Like I mentioned in the answer, if you hand anything a value as a float, it already has floating point precision. For example, `5.6 * 3` in your interpreter returns `16.799999999999997`. Handing that value to `str()` isn't going to change it in any meaningful way before converting to string. Your choices are either apply some type of rounding or start by using `Decimal`s at the source, which my answer does.

Answer (score 0):

*Yet whenever I run it, even though I've included decimal.Decimal() in my code, the result continues to be unrounded.*

This is compliant with what `decimal.Decimal` is supposed to do according to [its docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal-objects):

> class decimal.Decimal(value="0", context=None) Construct a new Decimal
> object based from value. (...) If value is a float, the binary
> floating point value is losslessly converted to its exact decimal
> equivalent. This conversion can often require 53 or more digits of
> precision. For example, Decimal(float('1.1')) converts to
> Decimal('1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625').

As side note `decimal.Decimal` is class, not function.

*to generate a human readable result, we can either use the round function on our result or use the decimal.Decimal() function.*

Beyond these you might decide to format your output for example using so-called [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/), for example if I want to have 4 digits after decimal:

```
x = 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1
print(x)  # 0.30000000000000004
print(f'{x:.4f}')  # 0.3000
```

Keep in mind f-string are available only in python3.6 and newer and if you have to use older version consider using other methods of formatting.

Comment: Is there any way to convert a float value to Decimal in terms of the variable itself rather than use an f-string or some other formatting tool to merely change the printed output?